# How to show collaboration diagram in Doxygen only for objects/classes related to a specific group tag

Tags: scripting, doxygen

I have created a markdown file as part of a c++ project intended to describe a specific functionality in the project.

In this markdown file, I have defined a group using '\defgroup myGroup Explanation of group'

I've also tagged all objects related to this group by including the \ingroup tag for the group in question.

The question is on how to render UML diagrams only for the context for this specific group in the detailed section of the module for this functionality?

I have read through the doxygen documentation and have not found any information on how to define the group context boundaries for rendering a specific group of objects/classes using graphviz.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


/**
 * @ingroup markingsgroup
 * @brief This class defines a base class
 */
class BaseClass
{
  public:

    BaseClass() {}

    virtual bool getStatus(void) const = 0;
    virtual void setStatus(const bool status) = 0;
};

/**
 * @ingroup markingsgroup
 * This class defines Class1
 */
class Class1 : public BaseClass
{
  public:

    Class1() {}

    bool getStatus() const
    {
      return m_status;
    }

    void setStatus(const bool status)
    {
      m_status = status;
    }

    private:
    bool m_status;
};

/**
 * @ingroup markingsgroup
 * This class defines a Class2
 */
class Class2 : public BaseClass

{
  public:

    Class2() {}

    bool getStatus() const
    {
      return m_status;
    }
    void setStatus(const bool status)
    {
      m_status = status;
    }

  private:
  bool m_status;

};

/**
 * @ingroup markingsgroup
 * @brief Main function
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Class1 myClass1;
  Class2 myClass2;

  myClass1.setStatus(true);

  myClass2.setStatus(myClass1.getStatus());

  std::cout << "Class1: " << myClass1.getStatus() << " Class2: " << myClass2.getStatus() << std::endl;
}
```

Doxyfile changes form default:

```
 PROJECT_NAME = "My Project"
 PROJECT_NAME = "Marking Project"
 OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = /home/fblidner/doxgentest/documentation
 EXTRACT_ALL = YES
 EXTRACT_PRIVATE = YES
 EXTRACT_PACKAGE = YES
 EXTRACT_STATIC = YES
 EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS = YES
 INPUT = project
 RECURSIVE = YES
 GENERATE_XML = YES
 XML_PROGRAMLISTING = NO
 UML_LOOK = YES
 CALLER_GRAPH = YES
 PLANTUML_JAR_PATH = /home/fblidner/puppet-manifests/devvm/files/generated/plantuml.jar
 MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH = 10 
 HAVE_DOT = YES
 CALLER_GRAPH = YES
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you talking about? Can you create a small example showing what you want (and include it in the question along with the settings different from the default doxygen configuration file)?

Comment: I'm currently using Doxygen version 1.8.13

Comment: Added the sample code. What i would like is to get the classes and functions which is tagged for a specific group using the tag @ingroup to be displayed as a relationship graph/diagram in the (Doxygen) module for the group in question. The module is defined as a markdown file including the tag \defgroup markingsgroup. When I add the \defgroup tag in the markdown file, I see that a module is created (including the classes I've included in the group) in the output from doxygen but no diagrams. What do I need to make this happen?

Comment: still missing the "(and include it in the question along with the settings different from the default doxygen configuration file)" and the `md` file but this can probably be a one liner. But I don't think it is possible what you want, you want more or less create a class / namespace based in the group, is this assumption correct?

Comment: where are the settings? Just edit them into the question (returns don't go well with comments).

Comment: UML_LOOK               = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
PLANTUML_JAR_PATH      = /home/fblidner/puppet-manifests/devvm/files/generated/plantuml.jar
2458c2458
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 10

Comment: The markdown file only includes:

@defgroup markingsgroup Track markings

Comment: The Doxyfile settings in the comments are unreadable, like I said they should have been in the question, I did it now.

Comment: I'm missing the `HAVE_DOT=YES` for the `CALLER_GRAPH=YES` setting

Comment: The HAVE_DOT and CALLER_GRAPH was allready set to YES in my Doxyfile. Added them to the question section..